# CodeIgniter: Validate datetime field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried This code, but the error is not display.

```
$this->form_validation
     ->set_rules('fromdatetime',
                 'fromdatetime',
                 '|required|valid_date[m/d/y,/]');
```

How can I validate the **datetime** format using **codeigniter** set rules.

Comment: Which date format you are using : try this reference http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/05/date-validation-for-codeigniter-2.html

Comment: I use this 2013-09-24 12:01:00 datetime format

Comment: jsut try this, valid_date[Y-m-d,/] , am not sure , hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this (dd/mm/yyyy):

```
$this->form_validation
     ->set_rules('fromdatetime',
             'Date',
             'required|regex_match[\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))]');
```

Change the regular expression if you want to use a different `format`. You may also use a `custom callback` function like this:

```
public function checkDateTime($dt)
{
    $pattern = 'same regex pattern';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $this->input->post('fromdatetime'))) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkDateTime', 'Invalid Date!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Set the `rule` as:

```
this->form_validation
    ->set_rules('fromdatetime', 'Date','required|callback_checkDateTime');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extended library:

https://github.com/lumoz/codeigniter-form-validation