# How to validate the datetime format using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('departure_date', 'Departure Date', 'required');
```

I tried this above code. But the error message is not displaying.

Comment: Do you have <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> in view ?
Show more source code.

Comment: You need to validate the format of datetime field and you are checking for required validation only.

Comment: I want check both required and correct format of datetime.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you nned to use this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('departure_date', 'departure_date', 'required|regex_match[\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Field required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE){
   //code if validation is correct
}
```

in your view:

```
<input type="text" name="departure_date"/>
<?php echo form_error('departure_date'); ?>
```

Comment: Its show the error when the departure_date is not filled.But i want to check empty,and datetime format(04/28/2014 12:17:13 PM).

Comment: Its show the  required error.but not display under this field. I have the form filed like this  array(
     'type' => 'datetime',
     'id' => 'arrival_date',
     'label' => 'Arrival Date',
     'desc' => '',
     'class' => 'span3',
     'default' => post_default('arrival_date',$todatetime_res),
     'options' => '', 
    ),

Answer (score 0):

try to validate date (dd/mm/yyyy):

```
$this->form_validation
     ->set_rules('departure_date',
             'Departure date',
             'required|regex_match[\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))]');
```

or use regex for datetime :-

```
$exp = '/^([0-9]{4})([\-])([0-9]{2})([\-])([0-9]{2})[\ ]'
.'([0-9]{2})[\:]([0-9]{2})[\:]([0-9]{2})$/';
```

and your view for display error use `form_error()`

```
<input type="text" name="departure_date"/>
<?php echo form_error('departure_date'); ?>
```

For more :- [CodeIgniter: Validate datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126794/codeigniter-validate-datetime-field)